# How to change text color of table header on iOS 5?

Tags: uitableview, ios5

How to change text color of table header on iOS 5 without using `viewForHeaderInSection` to create entire header view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add on `viewDidLoad`:

```
    [[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class], nil] setShadowColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```